# Magento migration error

Tags: magento, dedicated-hosting

domain Magento setup on a shared hosting account and have recently taken the dive in to a dedicated server environment.

We've copied the files across as they were on the old server but we're getting a 500 error.

On further investigation its:

```
PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object in /app/Mage.php on line 298
```

(have removed full actual path from this error for security)

Has anyone come across this problem before and if so how did you solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some solutions in the Magento Forum.

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/v%3Cfont%20color=/viewthread/177528/#t282767)

- Have you write permission on /var/ and all other folders that need write permissions?
- PHP Safemode off?
- Cache clear?

Comment: Brilliant... was PHP Safemode! easy solution in the end, thank you!

Comment: No problem in the mean time its only one parameter and nothing is running :D @Vince Pettit